# How to count Null and Not Null records in multiple columns in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I need the code for tableau to run the following scenarios. My data has 3 columns with some having values and some are null records. [Please see a sample of the dataset values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuPyz.png).

Can someone suggest an approach or give me a way to do this?

When I try the following code:

```
Count(CASE WHEN ISNULL([ColumnA]) AND NOT ISNULL([Column B]) THEN DataEC-MY ELSE NODATA END)
```

I see the count is not matching when I do the same in Excel. I have to do this task in Tableau to generate a report with the count of the above combinations. First is to compare Column A with Column B, then Column A with Column C values, and then Column B and Column C values. The objective is to get the count based on the above combination of null and non-null records.

Comment: so as per image what is your expected data in total column, post that aswell

Answer (score 0):

So you want to count the amount of row per column which has not null and null values?